# How to redeploy instance using API in rancher

Tags: rancher

I was able to rollback pod. However, I am not able to redeploy. Following is query.

```
curl -u "auth" -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"replicaSetId":null}' 'URL?action=rollback'
```

Is any one know how to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

I agree it will be nice to have `redeploy` action in the API. But for now you can use the following workaround (taken from [official rancher forum](https://forums.rancher.com/t/service-upgrade-image-pull-via-the-api/11494/6), but I fixed some headers due to errors):

```
pod_upgrade_body=$(curl -u "token-[use your token here]" \
-s 'https://rancher.mydomain.com/v3/project/c-zqpm5:p-h884r/workloads/deployment:development:api' \
-X GET \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 2>&1 | sed  "s/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\"\:\"[0-9T:Z-]*\"/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\":\"$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")\"/g")

curl -u "token-[use your token here]" \
-s 'https://rancher.mydomain.com/v3/project/c-zqpm5:p-h884r/workloads/deployment:development:api' \
-X PUT \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary "$pod_upgrade_body" --compressed
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating the answer for current 2.6 rancher:

```
url='https://yourdomain'
cluster=c-m-yourcluter
app=yourappname
namespace=probablyisDefault
token=token-name:keyvalue


pod_upgrade_body=$(curl -s -u "$token" \
-k $url/k8s/clusters/$cluster/v1/apps.deployments/$namespace/$app \
-X GET \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 2>&1 | sed  "s/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\"\:\"[0-9T:Z-]*\"/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\":\"$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")\"/g")

curl -u "$token" \
-k -s $url/k8s/clusters/$cluster/v1/apps.deployments/$namespace/$app \
-X PUT \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary "$pod_upgrade_body" --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here with JavaScript**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const version = '....'
// const version = '....'

const cluster = 'c-m-...'
const namespace = 'test'
const application = 'test'

const url = `https://rancher-.../k8s/clusters/${cluster}/v1/apps.deployments/${namespace}/${application}`
const token = 'token-...:...'
const headers = {
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // console.log(data);

    // update timestamp to redeploy
    // const newTimestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    // data.spec.template.metadata.annotations['cattle.io/timestamp'] = newTimestamp

    // update image to deploy another image
    data.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = `registry....:${version}`
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      // .then((response) => response.json())
      // .then(console.log)
  })
  .catch((exception) => {
    console.error(exception)
  });
```