# Convert sed command from cUrl to Powershell

Tags: powershell, http, curl

I'm trying to convert the commands from [How to redeploy instance using API in rancher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659998/how-to-redeploy-instance-using-api-in-rancher) to powershell.

```
pod_upgrade_body=$(curl -u "token-[use your token here]" \
-s 'https://rancher.mydomain.com/v3/project/c-zqpm5:p-h884r/workloads/deployment:development:api' \
-X GET \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 2>&1 | sed  "s/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\"\:\"[0-9T:Z-]*\"/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\":\"$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")\"/g")
```

This is my attempt but I can't seem to make it work

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri https://rancher... -Header @{Accept = 'application/json'; Authorization = 'Bearer [my-token]'; 'Content-type' = 'application/json'; Pragma = 'no-cache'; 'Cache-Control' = 'no-cache'}  |cat %{$_ -replace "s/\`"cattle.io/timestamp\`":\`"[0-9T:Z-]*\`"/\`"cattle.io/timestamp","$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")\`"/g"}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$_ -replace "s/\`"cattle.io/timestamp\`":\`"[0-9T:Z-]*\`"/\`"cattle.io/timestamp","$(date -u 
+"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")\`"/g"'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you're receiving JSON data, it is **better to use [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod)** than [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest).
- Doing so means that the **JSON response is automatically parsed into a `[pscustomobject]` *object graph* that allows direct OO access** to the data returned for easy, dot-notation-based querying and updating.
- You can can re-convert to JSON using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) (beware the default serialization depth of just `2`: use `-Depth` as needed).

To put it all together:

```sh
$fromJson = 
  Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri https://rancher... -Headers @{Accept = 'application/json'; Authorization = 'Bearer [my-token]'; 'Content-type' = 'application/json'; Pragma = 'no-cache'; 'Cache-Control' = 'no-cache' }  |
    ForEach-Object { 
      $_.annotations.'cattle.io/timestamp' = Get-Date ([datetime]::UtcNow) -UFormat '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
    } 

# Re-convert to JSON, if needed.
# Adjust -Depth as needed.
$fromJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
```

Note: I'm *assuming* that the `cattle.io/timestamp` properties are inside `annotations` property, based on the forum link in your question.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- In *Windows PowerShell* (but not PowerShell (Core) 7+), `cat` is a built in alias for [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), which reads text files specified by their *paths* - it doesn't support receiving *data* via the pipeline, the way that `cat` Unix utility does.
- However, there is no need for such a utility; the use of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, whose built-in alias `%` you tried to use, by itself is sufficient to process each input object via the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed to it, inside of which the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) refers to the input object at hand.
- The translation of the `sed` command into a [`-replace` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) has several problems:

  - `-replace` doesn't support `sed` functions such as `s` - it *is* the `s` (string substitution) function in a manner of speaking.
  - The search regex and the replacement string must be passed as *separate arguments* (and each must not be enclosed in `/.../` delimiters).
  - `-replace` doesn't support options (other than inline regex option in the regex operand), and it invariably replaces *all* occurrences; that is, `sed`'s `/g` option is *implied*.
- The external `date` utility is only available on Unix-like platforms by default; PowerShell's equivalent is the [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) cmdlet, as shown above.